# Lock screen not working

Tags: lock-screen, budgie, 21.10

Since updating to Ubuntu 21.10 my lock screen is not working anymore. I'm using budgie desktop and pressing <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to lock my screen this happens in syslog:

```
Oct 30 07:58:35 lenovo gsd-media-keys[9616]: message repeated 10 times: [ Couldn't lock screen: GDBus.Error:org.freedes
ktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.Shell.ScreenS
hield was not provided by any .service files]
Oct 30 08:01:21 lenovo budgie-panel.desktop[122417]: WARNING : Error getting shell mode
Oct 30 08:01:21 lenovo budgie-panel.desktop[122417]: CRITICAL: Error getting shell version
Oct 30 08:01:21 lenovo budgie-panel.desktop[122417]: WARNING : Could not list shell extensions
Oct 30 08:01:21 lenovo budgie-panel.desktop[122417]: Traceback (most recent call last):
Oct 30 08:01:21 lenovo budgie-panel.desktop[122417]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_a
ppearance.py", line 144, in __init__
Oct 30 08:01:21 lenovo budgie-panel.desktop[122417]:     extensions = self._shell.list_extensions()
Oct 30 08:01:21 lenovo budgie-panel.desktop[122417]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/gshellwrapper.py", l
ine 76, in list_extensions
Oct 30 08:01:21 lenovo budgie-panel.desktop[122417]:     return self._proxy.proxy_extensions.ListExtensions()
Oct 30 08:01:21 lenovo budgie-panel.desktop[122417]:   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/overrides/Gio.py", line 
349, in __call__
Oct 30 08:01:21 lenovo budgie-panel.desktop[122417]:     result = self.dbus_proxy.call_sync(self.method_name, arg_varia
nt,
Oct 30 08:01:21 lenovo budgie-panel.desktop[122417]: gi.repository.GLib.GError: g-dbus-error-quark: GDBus.Error:org.fre
edesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.gnome.Shell.Extensions” on object at path /org/gnome/Shell (1
9)
Oct 30 08:01:21 lenovo dbus-daemon[1711]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' uni
t='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.167' (uid=1000 pid=122417 comm="/usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/g
nome-tweaks " label="unconfined")
```

Comment: Same problem. I see `budgie-screensaver` mentioned in other questions but it's nowhere to be found in Ubuntu Budgie 21.10

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution here:

https://discourse.ubuntubudgie.org/t/lockscreen-not-working-after-update-to-21-10/5394/20

> right - so gnome-shell is screwing up budgie here.
>
> Does this work?
>
> pkill -9 -f /usr/bin/gjs /usr/share/gnome-shell/org.gnome.ScreenSaver
> Wait a couple of seconds then try running
>
> gnome-screensaver

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the idea! I had the same problem when upgraded from Ubuntu Budgie 20.04 to 22.04 and "Lock" button stopped working. It started working again after removing gnome-shell: `sudo apt-get remove gnome-shell`.

But (!) in result unfortunately all the icons on my desktop stopped working and clicking any icon does nothing even after re-installing gnome-shell.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1228479)